# spark workers simultaneously Updating same row of Mysql Table

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to run a spark Job on a Standalone Cluster(M+3Workers).

My job is defined by "By transaction details Update Customer Count" I:e. I will get a batch/Streaming file/record(Say 100 Transaction) to process and My spark job 'for a customer id if transaction found- go to mysql-Table and increase Transaction_count for that customer by 1'.

Currently it-is-working-Fine, But my concern is:: suppose each of my Worker got record of same customer(of course in their shared-RDD-part) and tried to update the Trx_count for that customer in same Mysql-table SIMULTANEOUSLY.

Will i face a lock in that Table??

Or Spark handles it some other way(No Clear Idea), so that it never happens till date and possibly never happens in future also??

Need some insight how spark is doing that Updating Job(Plan) ??

Comment: As we are getting transaction details, it's very much possible for multiple workers try update same customer row(may/may-not be same time). So, better add row level locking for updates at MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Perform reduceByKey with client-id as key and sum as reduce function as mentioned [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html), it will return pair of (client-id, count of transactions).
2. Now fire a single SQL query to directly update aggregate count for that client.

This will avoid any race condition and also will fire fewer SQL query.

Comment: @Tushar-let me try this.